# Protecting PHP files from being called by other websites

Tags: php, data-protection

I have a website which fetches data from some PHP files to display it on the website. However, to protect my data to be used by other people, I wish to protect my PHP file being called by crawlers, bot etc to gather data.

I have prevented it by checking referral URL , but that can be easily by-passed. So, is there any other way to protect my data . I wish that only my website can call to those files.

Thanks !!

Comment: Create an API that uses access tokens, and verify those tokens when somebody requests data.

Comment: The short answer is no. There is nothing fool proof that you can do to prevent this, because of the half duplex request-response nature of HTTP. The only thing you can do is require authentication before serving the protected content.

Comment: Since all those files are called through Ajax, any attempt to generate some auth code can be easily obtained by checking my Javascript code :(

Comment: @PrashantSingh Not if you use some form of cookie auth that requires the user to log in first through e.g. an HTML form. The cookies will be sent a long with the Ajax requests, no further JS code necessary. The same goes for HTTP standard auth, horrible as it is.

Comment: @DaveRandom Can I use a session variable for the same which will be initiated by index file ?

Comment: You can, but make sure learn about [session hijacking](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+session+hijacking) before relying on sessions for authentication. A RESTful token-based solution would be better.

Comment: What if the websites you are scraping do this thing LOL -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by DaveRandom, I finally used a cookie based authentication technique to avoid calling of PHP by other websites.

The server first sets a access code for each valid client. This access code is checked at the beginning of my PHP file.

Cookie is set a max time limit of 5 hrs and cookie is destroyed on window close. This is working pretty fine for me.

Please mention if there is any glitches in this part !!

Answer (score 1):

Add [Basic HTTP authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) in top of your php file:

```
if ( !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || 
      !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ||
      !($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'user' && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'pw'))) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Mirkwood"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Apache web server and in root directory of your site you create an .htaccess file (dot htaccess with no suffix).

Try this syntax to prevent access to specific file types:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|php)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

---

Another way is in all non-index php files you could include something like this:

In index.php, add an access value like this:

```
$access = 'my_value';
```

In every other file, include this check before even a single byte is echoed out by php:

```
if(empty($access)) {
    header("location:index.php"); 
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a website which fetches data from some PHP files to display it on the website.

Move the files that contain the data outside of the document root.  Assuming that the PHP files are just being accessed by another inside the docroot.